# RewriteRule not rewriting with matching regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm attempting to get apache to rewrite a request to `mysite.com/blog/<number>` to the file `/blog.php?page=<number>`. However, using a regex which does match that path, the URL is not rewritten and instead a 404 is returned as `/blog/` is a nonexistent directory.

Here is the `RewriteRule` I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/[0-9]+/? /blog.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I haven't used apache in quite a while, so I may have forgotten some extremely simple item which is required, but I cannot see anything wrong with the rule.

**Edit:**

RewriteRules from `httpd.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not grouping the numbers after `^blog/` using round brackets, that's why `$1` will be empty.

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to have worked. I still receive `The requested URL /blog/54 was not found on this server.` when attempting to access the blog URL.

Comment: Ok back to basics. Are you sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled and working?

Comment: mod_rewrite definitely is (using it to redirect HTTP->HTTPS). I'm not sure about .htaccess, but adding the rule to httpd.conf (trying both `^blog/...` and `^/blog/...`) does not work.

Comment: Oh if you already have some rules in your .htaccess then post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: .htaccess is empty aside from this rule.

Comment: But you commented about http->https rule?

Comment: That's in httpd.conf, not .htaccess. Added to main question, though.

Comment: Well in that case 50% my suspicion resurfaced? Are you sure this .htaccess is enabled & working? Also is there any .htaccess in blog directory any where else also?

Comment: There is no blog directory or any .htaccess in any other directory. In case .htaccess isn't enabled, I moved your rule into httpd.conf (placed just under the HTTP->HTTPS rule), and tried the regex with both `^blog/...` and `^/blog/...`.

Comment: For `httpd.conf` correct rule will be: `RewriteRule ^/?blog/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` Then 1. Make sure apache is bounced after this and 2. blog.php is available in `DocumentRoot`

Comment: That does not appear to have worked. Replaced the previous rule in `httpd.conf` with this one, restarted via `service httpd resart`, and still receive a 404 message. Is there any other directive in `httpd.conf`, or some default behaviour to be overriden, that may be forcing apache to look for a directory rather than follow the RewriteRule?

Comment: You need to just rename `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` for testing purpose.

Comment: OR another thought. Can you comment out `HTTP->HTTPS` rule and restart Apache to test this rule again. I suspect HTTPS DocumentRoot might be different.

Comment: It works correctly (in `httpd.conf`) when I comment out my HTTPS redirect rules (which are in the main question) and access over HTTP.

Comment: Ok thats what I thought too. Your `http->https` rule is firing first and making URL as `https://` but in your `VirtualHost` entry you have different `DocumentRoot` set and hence `/blog.php` isn't found.